# Stuck in failsafe xterm session

Tags: linux-mint, x11, desktop-environment

When I log in through the login screen, I'm presented with the following message:

> This is the failsafe xterm session.  To get out of this mode type 'exit' in the window in the upper left corner

Along with an OK button that brings me to a small terminal in the top left of the screen. Once I exit, the system brings me back to the login screen.

I am able to launch applications from the terminal such as Chrome, though the windows take up less than half of the screen with no way to resize them.

This happened after I rebooted into Windows. I have checked `.xsession-errors` and it only has one line that says beginning X session or something like that. I have also ran `apt-get` and upgrade all of the packages, however the issue still persists. On the login screen there is an option to choose Default or Cinnamon, neither of which work.

I'd like to know how I can get my normal desktop back.